# All roots of the quartic equation $a x^4 + b x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ cannot be real

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, quartics

#### Problem

> Prove that all roots of $a x^4  + b x^3  +  x^2  +  x  + 1 = 0$ cannot be real. Here $a,b \in   \mathbb R$, and $a  \neq  0$.

#### Source

This is one of the previous year problem of Regional Math Olympiad (India). I had a hard time solving it, so thought I'd better ask here.

#### Observations

- Some real roots are possible: when $a<0$, the equation   has  two of them.
- If one more coefficient was allowed to be arbitrary: $a x^4  + b x^3  +  cx^2  +  x  + 1 = 0$, then the roots could be all real, since every quartic can be brought into such form by scaling

Comment: If $x=1$ is not a root you can apply Rolle's theorem to $f(x)(x-1)$.

Comment: But what will that give me.

Comment: But please share some of your thoughts and give a bit of background. Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Rolle's theorem implies that if an evereywhere differentiable function has $n$ distinct zeros, then its derivative has at least $(n-1)$ distinct zeros.

Comment: It is one of the previous year problem of RMO. Had a hard time solving it, so thought I'd better ask it.

Comment: Can't this problem be solved using algebra, since I'm not very proficient in calculus.

Comment: Ok. So it is an old contest problem. Telling that was a plus to you. Also it wel help everybody gauge what kind of tools will be appreciated/allowed. Don't withold bits like that in the future!

Comment: Contest math problems often use "surprising" tools. Or a combination of tools. I'm familiar with RMO, but it wouldn't surprise me at all that a solution may require several tools and a few tricks :-)

Comment: How can it be "missing context or other details" when it is easily answered? Kindly see Elkies' answer and my comment.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I think the missing context is some effort on OP's part.

Comment: Is this problem really from India RMO 2012? where can I see it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + bx + a$.  Then the quartic
$ax^4 + bx^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is $x^4 f(1/x)$, and has four real roots
*iff* $f$ does.  But then the same is true of 
$f(x-\frac14) = x^4 + \frac58 x^2 + Bx + A$ for some $B$ and $A$
(we don't need the formula). 
If this is $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$ for some $a,b,c,d$
then $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = -2\frac58 < 0$, so $a,b,c,d$ cannot all be real,
**QED**.

Comment: If I may add something?  :)  In general, if $f(x) = x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s=0$, then the sum of the square of the roots $x_i$ is $S(p,q)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 = p^2-2q$. Hence $S(1,1)=-1$. Since the sum of the square of real numbers can't be negative, this implies not all the $x_i$ are real.

Comment: Noam, I would like to ask , how did you choose f(x). Is this a set procedure for this kind of problems or you chose it randomly.

Comment: @user2369284 See [Reciprocal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial).

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + bx + a$.  Then the quartic
$ax^4 + bx^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is $x^4 f(1/x)$, and has four real roots
*iff* $f$ does.  But $f''(x) = 12x^2 + 6x + 2 > 0$ for all $x$.
Therefore $f$ is convex upwards and hence can have at most two real roots, **QED**.

Answer (score 5):

Assume contrariwise that $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+x^2+x+1$ has 4 distinct real zeros for some choice of $a,b$. Then
$$
g(x)=f(x)(x-1)=ax^5+(b-a)x^4+(1-b)x^3-1
$$
has either five distinct zeros, or a double zero at $x=1$ together with three other zeros.

But
$$
g'(x)=5ax^4+4(b-a)x^3+3(1-b)x^2
$$
has a double zero at $x=0$, and at most two other zeros.

Rolle's theorem tells us that the derivative of a differentiable function has a zero between any two of its zeros. This rules out the possibility of $g(x)$ having five distinct zeros.

The remaining possibility is that $g(x)$ has a double zero at $x=1$ and three other zeros. This means that $x=1$ is one of the zeros of $g'(x)$, so by Rolle's theorem $g'(x)$ should have three zeros different from $x=1$. We saw that this cannot be the case, so we have arrived at a contradiction.

---

How to see this? The fixed part of the three lowest degree terms of the polynomial $f(x)$ is known to be a factor of $x^3-1$. With nothing else to go by, I decided to check out, where using that bit takes us.

Comment: I needed Rolle here, sorry :-(

Comment: It can also be a possibility that $g(x)$ has double zero at anywhere else other than 1. Also this only rules out that there can be 4 "distinct" real roots, not 4 real roots

Comment: @user2369284: Today I had reason to revisit this question. I see your objection now - somewhat belatedly. Very sorry about that. The argument becomes messier in those case. For example, if $f$ had real zeros $x_0<x_1<x_2<1$ of which $x_1$ is a double root, then $g'(x)$ should have a zero at $x_1$, and other zeros in the open intervals $(x_0,x_1)$, $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(x_2,1)$ which is again a contradiction. I haven't checked all the possibilities, but it seems to me that we always run into a contradiction with Rolle.

Comment: I cannot find the problem in this link: https://www.cheenta.com/problem-garden/indian-regional-math-olympiad/#section-442-485. Do you know where can I see proof that it is from RMO?