# Show that some of the root of the polynomial is not real.

Tags: polynomials, roots

\begin{equation*}
p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_3x^3+x^2+x+1.
\end{equation*}

All the coefficients are real. Show that some of  the roots are not real.

I don't have any idea how to do this, I only have an intuition that something is related to the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x$ and the constant 1.

Kindly help me!!

Comment: It is amazing that the three, low order coefficients can prevent all the roots from being real. (+1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adapting the argument from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/578472/11619) by Noam Elkies.

If $p(x)$ has only real zeros, then so does its reciprocal
$$
x^np(\frac1x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x+a_n.
$$
But by Vieta relations the sum of the roots of this polynomial is $-1$ and the sum of their pairwise products is $1$. Therefore the sum of the squares of the roots is
$$(-1)^2-2\cdot1=-1<0.
$$
Consequently some of the roots must be non-real.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the roots of $p(x)$. We have

- coefficient of $x^0 = 1 \implies \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = (-1)^n$
- coefficient of $x^1 = 1 \implies \sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{i=1,\ne j}^n \lambda_i = (-1)^{n-1}$
- coefficient of $x^2 = 1 \implies \sum_{1\le j < k \le n}\prod_{i=1,\ne j, k}^n \lambda_i = (-1)^{n-2}$

Combine these, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i} = -1
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sum_{1\le j < k \le n} \frac{1}{\lambda_j\lambda_k} = 1
$$
These together imply

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2} =
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i}\right)^2
- 2 \left(\sum_{1\le j < k \le n} \frac{1}{\lambda_j\lambda_k}\right)
= (-1)^2 - 2(1) = -1$$
If all $\lambda_i$ are real, the LHS has to be positive. Since this isn't the case, some of the roots are not real.

**Yet another alternate approach**

Since robjohn comes up an alternate approach using Sturm's Theorem, let's join the
fun and attack this problem with another theorem. Same as everyone else, if all the roots of $p(x)$ are real, so does 
$$q(x) = x^n p\left(\frac1x\right) = x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots$$
Apply [Gauss-Lucas theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) $(n-2)$ times, this will imply all the roots of the polynomial

$$\frac{1}{n!}q^{(n-2)}(x) = \frac12 x^2 + \frac{1}{n}x + \frac{1}{n(n-1)}
= \frac12 \left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \frac{n+1}{2n^2(n-1)}
$$
are real. However, this contradicts with the obvious fact the polynomial on RHS doesn't have any real root at all! As a result, some of the roots of $p(x)$ are not real.

Comment: (+1) I would normally do this the way that Jyrki or you did (which are essentially the same), but since you guys answered first, I had to do something different. I think Sturm's Theorem is pretty cool, too.

Comment: @robjohn one can also prove this using Gauss-Lucas theorem, it is also pretty cool.

Comment: Very cool indeed! I had forgotten about Gauss-Lucas. It can be very useful.

Comment: Wish I could +1 this again. Extensions of Rolle FTW :-)

Answer (score 3):

$p(x)$ has all roots in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if the polynomial $q(x)=x^np(\frac1x)$ has all its roots in $\mathbb{R}$. We don't need to worry about a root of $0$ since $p(0)=1$ and $q(0)=a_n\ne0$.

The first three polynomials of the [Sturm-Chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for $q(x)$ are
$$
\begin{align}
q(x)&=x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots\\
q'(x)&=nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^{n-2}+(n-2)x^{n-3}+\dots\\
q'(x)\left(\tfrac1nx+\tfrac1{n^2}\right)-q(x)&=\left(-\tfrac1n-\tfrac1{n^2}\right)x^{n-2}+\dots
\end{align}
$$
To have $n$ real roots, the lead coefficients of the Sturm-Chain must all have the same sign, so that there are $0$ sign changes at $+\infty$ and $n$ sign changes at $-\infty$. However, the lead coefficient of the third polynomial is different from the first two. Thus, $q(x)$ cannot have $n$ real roots and, likewise, $p(x)$ cannot have $n$ real roots.

---

Note that if $q$ has $d$ repeated roots then $\deg(\gcd(q,q'))=d$. Thus, the Sturm-Chain ends with a degree $d$ polynomial rather than a constant. This means we need $n-d$ sign changes to get the $n-d$ distinct real roots. This still means we need all the lead coefficients of the Sturm-Chain to have the same sign.

Answer (score 2):

If a polynomial has only real roots, its coefficients have to satisfy [Newton's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities).

Since by looking at the coefficients of $x^0,x^1,x^2$ we can see that this is not the case, our polynomial must have some non-real root (and obviously, non-real roots come in conjugated pairs).

Answer (score -3):

Counterexample: If $n=0$, then $p$ has no roots.

Comment: in the form given, $n\ge2$.